# Count over previously defined alias

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I'm trying to avoid writing twice the EXTRACT condition. There is any way to do that? Count over the previous alias  apparently is not valid.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DECADE FROM to_date(released_year::text, 'yyyy')) AS decade, 
    count(decade) AS total_by_decade
FROM album ...
```

Comment: no you can avoid it, you can only make a cte

Comment: I would love to know what is the problem of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can avoit it completely, but you can make a `CTE`

```
WITH
 CTE as(
SELECT EXTRACT(DECADE FROM to_date(released_year::text, 'yyyy')) AS decade 
 
FROM album ...)
SELECT  decade,  count(decade) AS total_by_decade FROM CTe GROUP BY decade
```